# How do you sort the list of favorites in Windows RT

Tags: favorites, windows-rt

On the Microsoft Surface RT, there are two instances of Internet Explorer.

The version that is started from the Desktop has the usual star icon for Favorites that brings up the list of Favorites in a sidebar. In this list, you can rename, delete, and order the list by name.

However, in the instance of IE that is accessible from the Start page, favorites appear as a list of large icons above the address bar after you click in the address bar. This display seems to show the same Favorites as you see in the Desktop IE, but in a seemingly random order. How can these be ordered by name?

Answer (score 0):

If you alphabetize your favorites in the IE version accessed from your Desktop first, the Favorites list accessible from the Start page is automatically alphabetized as well.  It's an extra step but worth it if the Favorites being in alpha order is important to you.